# EspSoftwareSerial with ESP8266: error no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'

Tags: arduino, esp8266, software-serial

i am trying to program with Arduino IDE 1.8.13 using EspSoftwareSerial library (target ESP8266).
Whatever example provided that I try to compile, I get an error (for example for the program "servoTester") :

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial swSer;
...


servoTester:4:16: error: no matching function for call to 'SoftwareSerial::SoftwareSerial()'
SoftwareSerial swSer;
```

I am not familiar with C ++ and Arduino (but I know C well on microcontrollers).
I'm a little bored, I've searched all over the place for solutions, and feel like I'm not the only one having this problem, but I haven't found a solution that works.

I tried to :

- change the <> by ""
- restart Arduino after installing the EspSoftwareSerial library
- Reinstall Arduino
- and various absurd things %-(

Does somebody have an idea ?

Comment: the constructor has two parameters as usual. the RX and TX pin numbers.

Comment: @Juraj: the espsoftwareserial library actually does have a SoftwareSerial() constructor (to my surprise), see https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial/blob/master/src/SoftwareSerial.h#L81

Comment: I would guess that somehow you are including the SoftwareSerial.h from the "regular" softwareserial library, and not from the espsoftwareserial library.